# How to get a SQLAlchemy session managed by zope.transaction that has the same scope as a http request but that does not close automatically on commit?

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope

I have a Pyramid web application with some form pages that reads data from database and write to it as well.

The application uses SQLAlchemy with a PostgreSQL database and here is how I setup the SQLAlchemy session:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

When I process a form, I need to perform an explicit commit surrounded in a `try` and see if the commit worked. I need this explicit commit because I have [deferrable triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createconstraint.html) in the PostgreSQL database (checks that are performed at commit time) and there are some cases where the absence of error is not predictable.

Once I successfully committed a transaction, for example adding an instance of MyClass, I would like to get some attributes on this instance and also some attributes on linked instances. Indeed, I cannot get those data before committing because they are computed by the database itself.

My problem is that, when I use `transaction.commit()` (in `transaction` package) the session is automatically closed and I cannot use the instance anymore because it is in *Detached* state. [Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy#long-lasting-session-scopes) confirms this point.

So, as mentioned in the documentation, I tried to use the following session setup instead:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(keep_session=True)))
```

However, now the session scope is not the same as the http request scope anymore : no ROLLBACK is sent at the end of my http requests that just perform read queries.

So, is there a way to have a session that have the same scope as the http request but that does not close automatically on commit?

Comment: as I've edited, this is more of a zope.transaction/pyramid integration issue.  you might want to ask on the pyramid mailing list for a quicker response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detach the session from the request via the `keep_session=True` on the ZTE. However, you probably also want to use the objects after the session is committed if this is the case, otherwise you'd be happy with a new session. Thus, you'll also want `expire_on_commit=False` on your session. After that, you've successfully detached the session from the lifecycle of pyramid_tm and you can commit/abort as you please. So how do we reattach it back to the request lifecycle without using pyramid_tm? Well, if you wrap your `DBSession` in something that's a little less global which will make it more manageable as a request-scoped variable, that'd help. From there, it's obvious when the session is created, and when it should be destroyed via a request-finished callback. Here's a summary of my prose:

```
def get_db(request):
    session = request.registry['db_session_factory']()
    def _closer(request):
        session.close()
    request.add_finished_callback(_closer)
    return session

def main(global_conf, **settings):
    config = Configurator()

    DBSession = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False, extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(keep_session=True))
    # look we don't even need a scoped_session anymore because it's not global, it's local to the request!

    config.registry['db_session_factory'] = DBSession

    config.add_request_method('db', get_db, reify=True)

def myview(request):
    db = request.db # creates, or reuses the session created for this request
    model = db.query(MyModel).first();
    transaction.commit()
    # model is still valid here
    return {}
```

Of course, if we're doing all this, the ZTE may not be helping you at all and you just want to use `db.commit()` and handle things yourself. The finished callbacks will still be invoked if an exception occurs, so you don't need pyramid_tm to cleanup after you.

Comment: It works perfectly except when my commit fails in the `try` block. Indeed, I perform a `transaction.abort()` in the `except` block but it does not seem enough because when I try to use the session again I get an error: `InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was ...`. Adding `request.db.rollback()` fixes the problem but I am forced to use both `Transaction.abort()` and `Session.rollback()` which does not seem clean.

Comment: If you're doing all these things, I'm not sure the ZTE is helping you at all.

Comment: That is right, I was just asking for the sake of understanding.